# Unable to replicate forecasts manually for SARIMAX

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, python, forecasting, arima

I am trying to manually replicate forecasts obtained by SARIMAX(0,1,1)(1,0,1,12) statsmodels v0.12.2 predict method.

You can find the dataset [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/fasahath/6f7f047f66fef49c4f4509c8cdb29296/raw/729e33bfbd1a0797b6febd999ea02a7362f42312/revenue_data.csv).
You can find the code to get forecasts based on model and equation [here](https://gist.github.com/fasahath/7f2225ddedc05f9bbaf3ca3de161508c)

Following is the result summary from statsmodels:
[image]

Considering the equation below for the SARIMAX(0,1,1)(1,0,1,12) to manually replicate the forecasts.

$
{SARIMAX(0,1,1)(1,0,1)_{12}} \\
y_i = {\Phi}_1*y_{i-12} + {\theta}_1*\epsilon_{i-1} + {\Theta}_1*\epsilon_{i-12}+ {\theta}_1*{\Theta}_1*\epsilon_{i-13} 
$


Above mentioned [code](https://gist.github.com/fasahath/7f2225ddedc05f9bbaf3ca3de161508c) does the following:

1. Fits SARIMAX model on [data](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/fasahath/6f7f047f66fef49c4f4509c8cdb29296/raw/729e33bfbd1a0797b6febd999ea02a7362f42312/revenue_data.csv) and gets predictions for the next 4 quarters
2. Fetch the model parameters ma.L1, ar.S.L12, ma.S.L12  to build equation
3. Difference the revenue data and get residuals from result.resid
4. Run forecasts using the equation
5. Compare the results

[image]
[image]

As you can the see the above plot, there is a slight difference in predictions from model vs the predictions from equation. Not sure what I am missing here!

PS:
I have seen other articles [similar to this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/394593/manually-calculate-sarimax-forecast/399103#399103) but I couldn't sort this out.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The issue comes from the MA terms, and is described at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/430186/how-statsmodels-predict-ma-process/430274#430274. Your approach here will work exactly when the sample size is larger, but in your case there is still a small impact from the "initialization" or "prior".

Comment: Yes, the impact is quite less. I will update this post when I perform this test on a larger sample size. Thanks for your inputs @cfulton.